# PLSQL: find and replace tag value in xml with the tag name to create sample data

Tags: html, xml, plsql

PLSQL

I want to replace the tag value with the tag name.
Input: String.
Output: Converted String.

example:
`<project>aQFH454</project><house>dvdrun</house>`

to:
`<project>project</project><house>house</house>`

Someone have an idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: user replace in sql, you can use if then statement in PL/SQL, to replace strings with something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using the function `REGEXP_REPLACE` and extracting the right regular expression groups:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(txt,'(<)(\w+?)(>)(\w+?)(</)(\w+?)(>)+','\1\2\3\2\5\6\7')
FROM (SELECT '<project>aQFH454</project><house>dvdrun</house>' txt FROM dual)
```

Where the group \2 is the tag name:

```
<project>project</project><house>house</house>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE ('<project>aQFH454</project><house>dvdrun</house>',
                       '<(.+)>.+</(\1)>',
                       '<\1>\1</\1>')
  FROM DUAL;
```